# Dictionary of parents, Add child

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hey guys I need to contain a database of multiple child objects. I was thinking of making a dictionary where the key is an int representing which type of child it is, then the second field being the parent object. Thought this way I could add any of the child objects to the Dictionary but I can't seem to get it to work? Any ideas of how to do this properly?

```
Dictionary<int, Parent> database;

ChildOne newChildOne = new ChildOne();
ChildTwo newChildTwo = new ChildTwo();

database.Add(1, newChildOne); 
database.Add(2, newChildTwo);
```

Comment: This won't work as you've described for one main reason (keys in a dictionary are unique). You're going to need to describe what you want...

Comment: Do `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` inherit from `Parent`? What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are you getting an error, or can you not figure out how to write what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need dictionary to hold parent-child relations.
Just create an class that can hold this relations:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntity(int entityId, MyEntity parent)
    {
        this.Children = new List<MyEntity>();
        this.EntityId = entityId;
        this.Parent = parent;
        this.Parent.Children.Add(this);
    }

    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    public MyEntity Parent { get; set; }

    public List<MyEntity> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Then just create this relations:

```
        MyEntity topParent = new MyEntity(1,null);
        MyEntity childOnLevel1 = new MyEntity(7,topParent);
        MyEntity childOnLevel2 = new MyEntity(4, childOnLevel1);
```